# Why does my ListView only create the child elements which are visible?

Tags: android, listview, scroll, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to make an app that consists of guessing certain words in a specific order.

I have 16 buttons on the right each one of them with a associated word. When I click the correct button the word in the ListView turns gray. The problem that I have encounter is that when I scroll in the listView and click the correct button the method getChildAt starts counting from the first visible element and not from the beginning of the listview; and I don't know how to fix it.

I am using an ArrayAdapter.

Here is where I set the Adapter:

```
// frutasLista is the array with the String elements that I want to add to the list.
((ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listaFrutas)).setAdapter(
                new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, frutasLista)
);
```

This is where I set the current element color to gray:

```
// contAciertos Is the counter where I save how many word the user guessed right.
((TextView) ((ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.listaFrutas)).getChildAt(contAciertos)).setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
contAciertos++;
```

When I click the correct element and I haven't done any scroll it works as it should
[First Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPxM0.png)

But If I do some scroll and click the first correct element again this happens:
[Second Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klH6N.png)

I have scrolled down to 'Platano' and clicked the first correct element which was 'Cereza'. And instead of turning gray the first element of the ListView as I'm trying to do. It changed the first visible element at that moment that was 'Platano'.

Thanks in advance.
Sorry if didn't explain myself clearly.

Comment: Don't update the view directly. Instead, update the list of data that is backing your adapter. Then your `getView()` method can correctly set the color based on the data in the adapter.

Comment: "Why does my ListView only create the child elements which are visible?" -> Because this is their purpose. If your list has 1,000 items you don't want to create the UI for all of them if your user can see only 10 at a time, it'll make the UI very laggy for no purpose.
Btw, you should use RecyclerView instead of ListView